# libpath et package loading order

Tags: r, path, package, version, lib

I have a question regarding the order in which packages are loaded.
let's suppose I have a libPath with 2 folders (in this order):

- folder1 (which contains external package EXTPACK version1)
- folder2 (which contains external package EXTPACK version2)

Now I have package MYPACK that imports EXTPACK, and specifies that it requires version >=2.

My question is: would R manage to find EXTPACK correct version which is in folder 2?

Thanks